# List iterators incompatible assertion fail

Tags: c++, debugging, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I cannot figure out why this exception is being thrown on the `remove`. I have the following code in Object.cpp:

```
//  Initialize class.
int Object::nextID = 0;
list<Object*> Object::objects;

Object::Object(string name)
{
    SetName(name);
    nextID++;
    objects.push_back(this);
}


Object::~Object()
{
    //  Remove from the list of objects.
    objects.remove(this);
}
```

From `Object` I derive other classes and objects are being created on the heap and relegated to `shared_ptr`s. There is no other code that refers to `Object::objects`, which is a static variable.

In the debugger (I'm using VS2013), I'm noticing weird stepping behaviour, with empty lines being stepped into and jumping around between code that's never called, so I'm not sure if this is a bug with VS2013. In case it makes a difference, I'm using some of the new features of C++11 elsewhere.

Besides, `objects` has size 0 when the destructor is called, even though I have seen it being incremented to 1 in the constructor. Can anyone help?

One more thing: the code runs just fine in GCC/Code::Blocks.

**Update:** I think I know why, though I need to find a solution: it's the order of destruction of static objects. I derive `GameObject` from `Object`, and I'm keeping shared pointers of `GameObjects` in another static variable, not `Object` pointers. Now those shared pointers release at program termination, but by that time the static list of raw `Object` pointers above may already be destroyed.

Comment: Didn't you forget to disable optimization in VS?

Comment: Optimization is diabled.

Comment: Possibly you are not running the code you think you are runnimg.  Add some `OutputDebugString`s to the code, recompile, and watch the debug output window.  Odds are very far against it being a compiler bug.

Comment: I think I know why, though I need to find a solution: it's the order of destruction of static objects. I derive `GameObject` from `Object`, and I'm keeping shared pointers of `GameObjects` in another static variable, not `Object` pointers. Now those shared pointers release at program termination, but by that time the static list of raw `Object` pointers is already destroyed. Christ.

Comment: Does Object have a copy constructor or assignment operator? The default ones won't do the right thing for you. (Rule of three.)

Comment: Can an Object ever be constructed before `objects` gets initialised?

Comment: I've disabled the copy constructors so they're not being called for sure. Assignment, there's none that I can see (very few lines of code so far) but it wouldn't hurt to create them I guess. As to your last question, is it even possible that an Object be constructed before its own static variable is initialized? I'm initializing in Object.cpp, so I don't think so..

Comment: @Kristian It is very definitely possible, I'm afraid - if there are static Objects, they are not guaranteed to be initalised before Object's static variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was *the order of destruction of static objects*. I derived `GameObjects` from `Objects` and kept a static list of shared pointers to the `GameObjects` and the static list above of raw pointers to `Objects`. The shared pointers were released on program termination, but by that time the raw pointer list was already destroyed, hence the assertion fail.

That was obviously a bad design decision.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger weird stepping behavior is typical of attempting to run a release build in the debugger. Use a debug build instead.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP, I asked my question because I (and entire team where I am working) always use release build but with disabled optimization, which allows correct debugger stepping. We use this during local builds on dev machines and on build server optimization is enabled

Comment: I've "solved" the `Object` list assert fail by removing the Object list, which so far I don't need. But the weird stepping is still there! I've tried rebuilding as well, same.